# Bind drop down list to calendar with conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I'm new to ASP.NET and C# and I'm having trouble completing a project.  I'm trying to create a page where a user can select an item from a drop-down list, which contains four options.  Each option is tied to specific days and times of the week.  I'm trying to make it so when a user selects an option where the specified days are Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, it makes it so the corresponding calendar only allows for Monday, Wednesday, or Friday to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

No way ofdoing this the way you want to. Check out some javascript calendar pickers that can be configured to only allow certain months and use that on front end.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, I cannot use javascript in this project.  I'll continue to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can store the current selection and then in the on select event if the event is one you don't want the user to select then reselect the stored (previous) selection?